# eclipse CDT view struct in debug

Tags: c++, eclipse, view, struct, gdb

In eclipse with CDT, I would like to view the values of a struct's members, similar to the way in which I can use the "variables view" to look at the values of variables.  Below is a very simple example where I would like to be able to examine the values of test.val1 and test.val2.  The program runs fine, but I can't use gdb to view struct test.

```
#include <cstdio>

struct test {
    int val1;
    int val2;
} test;

int main () {
    test.val1 = 3;
    test.val2 = test.val1*4;
    printf("val1 = %d, val2 = %d\n", test.val1, test.val2);

    return 1;
}
```

After I achieve this, my next question will be is there any difference is test is

```
extern "C" struct struct test {
    int val1;
    int val2;
} test;
```

I am running:
Eclipse IDE for Java Developers
Version: Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2)
with CDT, CDT SDK and Photran

Thanks for your help on this probably very simple question

Paul

Comment: In truth, this was a simplified version of my actual problem.  After dbrank0's response, which worked, I found that my code above also worked.  My non-simplified problem was to view structs that were actual external FORTRAN common blocks.  This is accomplished in the same way as above, but don't declare the struct as _extern "C"_.  Do, however declare the common blocks as structs so that gdb has information on them.  If they are initialized with a FORTRAN block data statement, remove this, and initialize them in the C code

Answer (score 0):

In your sample code you declared struct (type) named test and a struct variable of type test also named test. GDB seems to have an issue with this.

Modify your code, so type and variable have different name (so something like this):

```
struct Test {
    int val1;
    int val2;
} test;
```

Then start the debugger. In expressions view add new expression "test" and that is it.